# What are alternative options for configuring Postfix for sending newsletter emails through Django?

Tags: django, deployment, postfix-mta

I am trying to send a newsletter from my site. On average, 500 emails should be sent per mailing list. I'm trying to set up Postfix to do this and send emails through it.

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = example.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydomain = example.com
myorigin = $mydomain
mydestination = www.$mydomain, $myhostname, localhost.localdomain, localhost, localhost.$mydomain, $mydomain
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = all
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891
non_smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891
```

I want to send emails using django. And I use postfix mailing user, but when I try to send an email, nothing happens.

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'mailing@example.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '******'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
SERVER_EMAIL = 'mailing@example.com'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'mailing@example.com'
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it? Or maybe there are alternative options for my task, thanks in advance.

Set up postfix to send emails using Django. The error does not occur, but the letters do not come.